# Ajax request within iframe with easyXDM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe

I am using easyXDM to facilitate communication between a website and a shopping cart that is within an iframe and hosted on my domain.  When a user adds something to the shopping cart, I use easyXDM.Rpc to send the item information to the iframe shopping cart.  So far so good, but now I would like to call an ajax request from within the iframe cart on my domain to find the item and return the price.  I am unable to make any kind of ajax call, this is the code I am using:

On a website on another domain (the consumer):

```
var rpc= new easyXDM.Rpc({
        remote: remote_path,
        onReady: function(){
        },
        container: document.getElementById("cart"),
        props: {
            style: {
                border: "2px solid red",
                width: "200px",
                height: "300px"
            }
        }
    }, 
    remote: {
      fooBar: {}
    }

    //this submits the item info to add it to the cart
    $("#item_form").submit(function(){                               
      data = $("#menu_form").serialize();
      rpc.fooBar($(this).serialize());   
      return false;
    });
```

And then within the iframe shopping cart hosted on my domain (the provider):

```
var rpc = new easyXDM.Rpc({}, {
    local: {
        fooBar: function(data){
            //alert(data) works to show the item information and this is where I would like to make an ajax call with this info, something like:
            //$.get(add_to_cart_path, function(data){})                
            //rpc.post(add_to_cart_path, "this is a test")
        }
    },
    remote: {
        barFoo: {}
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/easyxdm/ky_XeiU-nqo